Abort trap when trying to run nested bhyve from FreeBSD kvm guest
I have a FreeBSD VM, which is running over Linux KVM, in which when I try to run a bhyve virtual machine I get the following error:
vm exit[0]
    reason      SVM
    rip     0x000000000f49eac0
    inst_length 2
    exitcode    0x7b
    exitinfo1   0x511021d
    exitinfo2   0xf49eac2
Abort trap

I am running KVM with the command:
/usr/sbin/bhyve -A -D -H -P -S -u -w -c 1 -m 250m -s 0,amd_hostbridge \
      -s 5,virtio-blk,FreeBSD-14.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso \
      -s 7,virtio-blk,guest.img \
      -s 29,virtio-rnd -s 21,virtio-net,tap0 -s 31,lpc \
      -l com1,stdio \
      -l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_UEFI.fd test

The FreeBSD VM is a fresh install of FreeBSD-14.1-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img, which is provisioned with the following script
pkg install -y bhyve-firmware
truncate -s 16G guest.img
fetch https://download.freebsd.org/releases/ISO-IMAGES/14.0/FreeBSD-14.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso
kldload vmm

And have already proved that the Linux KVM host is providing nested virtualization with a Linux guest which ran another KVM virtual machine.
Also I here the virt-manager xml of the FreeBSD VM:
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>freebsd</name>
  <uuid>88888888-8888-8888-8888-888888888888</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://freebsd.org/freebsd/14.0"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-i440fx-noble">hvm</type>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state="off"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on"/>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/var/local/freebsd.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
      <boot order="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x04" function="0x0"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="ide" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x06" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pci-root"/>
    <interface type="network">
      <mac address="52:52:52:52:52:52"/>
      <source network="default"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <sound model="ac97">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <audio id="1" type="none"/>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x08" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>

